# put images report on every page at absolute position

Tags: floats, sidewaysfigure, everypage

I'd like to have one specific image at the top left corner and another in the top right one. I tried doing this vith `\lhead` and `\rhead`, but it didn't position the images in the corners of the pages, but just above the text block.

The images are supposed to be in the corner of the entire page on every page.

Is there a way doing it?

Comment: Which class and packages do you use?

Comment: When I tried the solutions (given) with `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]`, I got the images properly on the page "where" I put the command, but on no other page.

Comment: I guess you put your comment on the wrong thingy (it looks like it should be below one of the provided answers and not your question).

Comment: Although the shifts didn't match at all, I got it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`background`](https://ctan.org/pkg/background) for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
   scale=1,
   angle=0,
   opacity=1,
   color=black,
   contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm] current page.north east)
            {\includegraphics[width = 3cm]{lion}} %
       node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm] current page.north west)
            {\includegraphics[width = 3cm]{lion}}; %<- change the name of image
     \end{tikzpicture}}
 }
 \begin{document}

 \lipsum[1-7]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `tikz` and `everypage`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt] at (current page.north east)
      {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt] at (current page.north west)
      {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]