# How to use a image in the 4 corners in every page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

i am trying to use a image in the 4 corners of every page, i have this code for one corner

```
\backgroundsetup{%
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example.jpg}},
position=current page.north east,
anchor=below left,
}
```

but with this i can just put an image on the top right corner, i cant find the instructions to put in the other corners, so i need help.

thank you

Comment: If your latex is fully up to date it is easier to use the new hook system and hook into shipout/background. It even include absolute positioning on the page

Comment: This might be of help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/568846/158639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by this link:[put images report on every page at absolute position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410029/put-images-report-on-every-page-at-absolute-position?rq=1) one solution is this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm] current page.north east)
            {\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{lion.png}} %
            node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm] current page.north west)
            {\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{lion.png}}% 
            node at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm] current page.south east)
            {\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{lion.png}}%
            node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=2cm] current page.south west)
            {\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{lion.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-7]
    
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]